# Detox take screenshot of the app when test fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, detox

I want Detox only to take a screenshot if the test fails and saving the photo with the test name, currently I didn't find anything in the Detox documentation that returns test's state or name in the afterEach hook.

```
afterEach(async function () {
  
  // if(test fails take screenshot) ...
  const screenshotPath = "./test.png";
  await device.takeScreenshot(screenshotPath);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to call `takeScreenshot` manually for failing tests since Detox can do this for you. You can either providing a value for the `screenshot` flag in your Detox App config JSON file:

For example:

```
artifacts: {
        plugins: {
            log: 'failing',
            screenshot: 'failing',
            video: 'failing'
         }
    }
```

Alternatively use the following parameter when calling `detox test`:

`--take-screenshots [manual/failing/all/none]`

More details are in the Detox docs for App Config [here](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/introduction/project-setup#step-2-app-configs) and the `detox test` CLI [here](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/cli/test)